# Rendering HTML Link in SSRS is omitting the target attribute

Tags: html, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SQL reporting services 2008 R2, and in one of my reports I am using the Placeholder text to render an html  link (anchor) to open a page **in another window**, 
The expression text is as below:

```
="<a target='_top' href=""http://www.google.com""  >Print</a>"
```

however, when the report is rendered in the browser,  the `target='_blank'` is not there, as if the SSRS renderer is ignoring it.

I tried before to use JavaScript to open in a new window, but that did not work on the client machine, because I am hosting the SSRS reports in an Iframe hosted in another web application, and both the web application and the SSRS report server are on different domains. This issue can't be solved using JavaScript according to this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f26ffa84-bd45-4643-bae1-d5252cdd0bf0/ssrs-2008r2-report-rendering-in-iframe-having-issues-opening-hyperlink-using-javascript?forum=sqlreportingservices)

So the question is why is the SSRS renderer ignoring my target="_blank" attribute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found it with the help of a friend, to force SSRS report to open links in a new window, just add the following Query string parameter to the URL of the report: `&rc%3ALinkTarget=_blank`
So for example the final url will be:

```
http://myreportserver/ReportServer?/MainSSRSFolder/MyReport&rc%3ALinkTarget=_blank
```

This will make all the links in the SSRS report open in a new window

Comment: I've been trying to do this and I get, an Invalid Path error

Comment: Yes, that attribute does make a difference. However, I am having a different problem. My report that is rendered in an iframe is not firing hyperlinks at all. Although, using the right mouse and selecting open in new tab works fine. Any idea?

Comment: So, what is it? HyperlinkTarget or LinkTarget? I am trying both, not working.

Answer (score 7):

I have done this before with javascript. On the "Action" tab of your link's Textbox properties, select "Go to URL". Then enter this script in the "Select URL" expression:

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank'))
```

If you need the URL to be passed by your dataset, you can do this:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('" & Fields!YourURL.Value & "', '_blank'))"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this. This works fine if the Parent website and the SSRS Iframe are both on the same domain, but when they are on different domains, this wont work, Check this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f26ffa84-bd45-4643-bae1-d5252cdd0bf0/ssrs-2008r2-report-rendering-in-iframe-having-issues-opening-hyperlink-using-javascript?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: @HassanMokdad referring to the link you posted, a happy medium to both using an `a href` and using a JavaScript action would be to embed the JavaScript action as an HREF: `="<a href=""javascript:void(window.open('http://www.google.com/'), '_blank')"">textbox text</a>"` (this is done in the textbox expression)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a `reportviewer control` in an ASP.NET page, you can also set the attribute `HyperlinkTarget="_blank"` to apply this to all links on the page without JavaScript calls.

Comment: Setting the ReportViewer control's HyperlinkTarget property to _blank did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Of course I can't really tell you *why* the designers chose this. I can probably get you the closest you can get to a confirmation that this in fact as designed, i.e. "*that* it is in fact ignoring the attribute".

The [MSDN lists supported HTML in SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519562%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), quoting that article:

> • Hyperlinks: `<A HREF>`
>
> • Fonts: `<FONT>`
>
> • Header, style and block elements: `<H{n}>`, `<DIV>`, `<SPAN>`, `<P>`, `<DIV>`, `<LI>`, `<HN>`
>
> • Text format: `<B>`, `<I>`, `<U>`, `<S>`
>
> • List handling: `<OL>`, `<UL>`, `<LI>`

From the first bit I'd *infer/guess* that *only* the `href` attribute on `a` tags is supported.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so it seems that target attribute will be ignored, do you know how can i overcome this issue, how to open in a new window

Comment: Don't think there *is* a solution, barring hacks with JS etc.

Comment: Check the solution I found, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For others who might be stuck on the accepted answer not working, the URL parameter is correct, but there is a mistake in the URL. The ampersand should be replaced with a question mark. Ampersand is generally used to separate parameters after the question mark separates the URL from the parameters to be used, if using just one parameter you want only the question mark and no ampersand.

> The question mark ("?", ASCII 3F hex) is used to delimit the boundary between the URI of a queryable object, and a set of words used to express a query on that object. When this form is used, the combined URI stands for the object which results from the query being applied to the original object.

https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html#:%7E:text=Query%20strings,applied%20to%20the%20original%20object.

The accepted answer is correct except for that one issue, which causes SSRS to crash when viewing the report.

Here is the example of a working report URL that opens in a new tab/window.

`http://[reportserver]/[MainReportsFolder]/report/[ReportSubFolder]/[MyNewReport]?rc:LinkTarget=_blank`

Everything in brackets should be changed out with your own appropriate values based on your SSRS setup.

I saw some others struggled with the accepted answer, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution I found.

`="javascript:void(window.open('" & "" & Fields!link.Value &"','rc:LinkTarget=_blank'))"`

Version 3.0 Report Builder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).